# Spring-boot : how to execute multiple test classes by just starting the service once using rest-assured

Tags: spring-boot, teamcity, rest-assured

I am writing my spring-boot tests using rest-assured and these annotations on the test class -

java class 1:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ApplicationSErvice.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest("server.port:8083")
public class MyTestClass{
}
```

java class 2:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ApplicationSErvice.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest("server.port:8083")
public class MyTestAnotherClass{
}
```

Question here is , if I have to execute both the java classes on the teamcity one after the other in the form of executing integration tests,then is there a way that I can have the annotation just in one class so that once the service is up and running all the tests can execute or there is no way and I have to put the annotations in all the classes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, you can

You can do it using inheritance:

Class with all the configuration

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ApplicationSErvice.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest("server.port:8083")
public class WebAppConfigTest {

}
```

First test class extending from `WebAppConfigTest`

```
public class MyTestClass extends WebAppConfigTest {
}
```

Second test class extending from `WebAppConfigTest`

```
public class MyTestClass extends WebAppConfigTest {
}
```

Comment: This really comes in handy when you want to test some Spring Data repositories with in memory test DB. Thank you !
By the way, WebAppConfigTest should not be empty, so I've put a NotNull test on my ApplicationContext in it.

Comment: @JRUtily you can call the class AbstractSomethingTest or avoid the word test so you don't have the "empty" problem